# "localhost refused to connect" when calling wcf rest service

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, wcf-binding

I created a wcf service with two different endpoints using basicHttpBinding and webHttpBinding. I have a asp mvc client consuming the basicHttpBinding endpoint and angular controller consuming the webHttpBinding. However when I call the endpoint using the webHttpBinding via browser and angular controller I am getting connection refused error. How can I fix this problem or what am I doing wrong (New to WCF).

Service Contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IVacationService
{
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "create",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    VacationDC RequestVacation(VacationDC vacation);

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "approved",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<VacationDC> GetApprovedVacations();

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "all", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<VacationDC> GetAllVacations();

    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "remove/{id}", Method = "DELETE",RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    void RemoveVacation(long id);
}
```

Web.config:

```
<services>
  <service name="WcfService.VacationService">
    <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="Soap" contract="WcfService.IVacationService" />
    <endpoint address="api"   binding="webHttpBinding" name="rest" contract="WcfService.IVacationService" behaviorConfiguration="webRest"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8092/vacation" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webRest">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Is your app and the service in different domains?   The `webHttpBinding` may not be working due to cross-domain calls.

Comment: I get the same problem when I run the wcf project as the start up project then invoke the rest uri from the browser, this wouldn't represent a cross domain call.

Comment: Could a network proxy be the reason for this problem?

Comment: Possibly, though I would expect locahost to bypass any proxies (I could be wrong on that).